# How to redirect to the camera native application from my browser using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, camera

I'm trying to do something that sounds pretty simple but I'm having trouble with that. I've found many articles teaching how to "create" a camera inside a web application or even how to open the camera also inside the web application, but in my case I only want to redirect the navigation to the native camera. I mean, I need a button that when it is pressed, it CLOSES the browser and OPENS the native camera application of the phone. Is it even possible? My website is built with ReactJS, so I think that anything in Javascript will work for me. Thank you all!

Comment: `<input>` for image files should work

Comment: Actually, <input> will open the camera inside the browser. I need something to close or minimize the browser and open the native camera application.

Comment: That's impossible I think.